# Complete language abbreviation list for vim's `set spelllang` option?

Tags: vim

I'm starting using vim's `spell` check function today. But seems it treat Chinese characters as wrong spell word.

Thus I did a little research, and find I should use `set spelllang=X` option.

But the thing is, I don't know what's the vim abbreviation for `Chinese` here. I tried `zh` and `cn`, both failed.

I did some searching on google, no result, either.

Does someone know in which file, web-page or help command resides this abbreviation reference list for all languages in `spelllang` option?

Comment: I see a list of dictionaries available under vim here: http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/ but I don't see Chinese listed among them.

Comment: @John1024, that's quite valuable, is there possible to make vim ignore all utf-8 code instead of treating them as wrong spelling word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The built-in `spellfile.vim` script will attempt to download missing spell files from http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell.

In general, spell checking is not supported for East Asian languages like Chinese and Japanese, because individual words are not separated by whitespace, so a different algorithm would be needed.

You probably want to

```
:set spelllang+=cjk
```

to avoid highlighting those. From `:help 'spelllang'`:

> If the name "cjk" is included East Asian characters are excluded from
>     spell checking.  This is useful when editing text that also has Asian
>     words.

Comment: It's you again, life saver!

Comment: Good! +1 (it makes sense: in cjk the notion of individual word with errors is not so clear...)

Comment: This feature seems to be pretty recent: not in 7.4.52 (Ubuntu 14.04), but in the source tree as you say.